# Microsoft Dynamics AX Windows 8 App connect to AOT

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, microsoft-dynamics

Microsoft is starting to do more with Windows 8 apps connecting to AX. Do they have any example solutions that show how they are creating this connection to AX and pulling data? How do they federate the connection?

See an app like this:

[Microsoft Dynamics AX Production Floor](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/cc07f817-e74c-48aa-86ad-1c0345fff989)

Answer (score 1):

It uses the mobile connector through an Azure service bus.
You can find a white paper on it named [Developing secure mobile apps for Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38413)

Comment: Yeah I was looking for more of a .NET starter app to get off the ground with too

Comment: During last technical conference, we asked for a dummy example or a model project. It's something MS is considering but with no promises.